# Probability of trains crossing in front of you, using Poisson Arrival Processes

Tags: probability, poisson-process

I was waiting at a train station when I thought of this problem. Suppose I know the average rate of arrival for trains coming in from the left and going out on right from the station, say $\lambda_1$, and an average rate of arrival for trains coming in from opposite direction, say $\lambda_2$.

What is the probability that if I wait for a time period T, I will see at least one pair of trains crossing right in front of me?

I also thought of a solution, but I am not sure if I am on the right track.
I designed a new Poisson Arrival process with a rate $\lambda$ = 1/LCM(1/$\lambda_1$,1/$\lambda_2$). Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: You have to make assumptions about how long a passing train is "right in front" of you. If the width of this time window is $0$ the probability you are asking for is $0$ as well.

Comment: Suppose I take the station to have a width, d and assume that each train spends a time t from entering to completely exiting the station in this distance. How can I go forward with solving this now?